# Problem with SQLite connection with LibreOffice

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04
Libreoffice Base ver. 5.1.6.2
DB Browser 3.11.99

Following How can I install SQLite to be used with OpenOffice? .

(If you click the icon above to install libsqliteodbc, make sure that you also install the AddOn “Graphical tools for ODBC management and browsing (unixodbc-bin)” (so, make sure the checkbox is ticked).).

1. No option to install the AddOn   “Graphical tools for ODBC management”.
2. On Alt+F2 ODBCConfig. Click the icon nothing append but found:
   ODBCCreateDataSource.eQ4
   ODBCManageDataSource.cesQ4
   Can I use one any this two to config ?
   I need guide on this please
   Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to install both `unixodbc`and `libsqliteodbc`.

```
sudo apt install unixodbc libsqliteodbc
```

This automatically installs the driver declaration in /etc/odbcinst.ini. Then you will need to declare your databases in a file `.odbc.ini` in your home folder. This config file looks like

```
[mydatabase] 
Description=Description of your database 
Driver=SQLite3 
Database=<full path and name of your sqlite3 database file 
# optional lock timeout in milliseconds 
Timeout=2000
```

For each database, you need to access a similar block. To be sure, restart your system. You should now be able to connect to these databases from within Libreoffice Base.