# SQLite connection with LibreOffice error

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04

Libreoffice Base ver. 5.1.6.2

DB Browser 3.11.99

After following the explanation from [my last question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133281/problem-with-sqlite-connection-with-libreoffice) I come to an error.
While connecting Base with SQLite click on Test Connection, this error shows:

`[unixODBC][Driver Manager] Data Source name not found, and no default driver specified`

I setup odbcinst.ini and .odbc.ini according to instructions.

I don't understand why this error.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the driver must be downloaded, compiled and installed, and then the ODCB configuration files need to be edited (cf. [Thej](https://thejeshgn.com/2018/08/23/using-sqlite-with-libreoffice-base-on-linux/#Install-SQLIte-ODBC-Driver), 2018) from this [site](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/).

[Thej](https://thejeshgn.com/2018/08/23/using-sqlite-with-libreoffice-base-on-linux/#Install-SQLIte-ODBC-Driver) (2018) also gives further detailed explanations on how to set up SQLite and ODBC correctly for use with Libreoffice Base.